# How is constrain.js and kimbo.js documentation generated?

Tags: javascript, documentation

I've come across two examples of documentation I'd like to try and implement:

http://kimbojs.com/api

http://cjs.from.so/api

The `kimbo` source code seems to have css references to `cjs`, so I thought perhaps it was being generated by `cjs`, but I can't see the connection yet.

The `cjs` repo also has references to [docco.css](https://github.com/soney/constraintjs/tree/master/resources) and [dox.js](https://github.com/soney/constraintjs/tree/master/resources/api_doc_generator/lib), which themselves seem to be related to different documentation solutions:

https://jashkenas.github.io/docco

https://github.com/tj/dox

So at this point I got confused.

**Question**

How is `constrain.js` and `kimbo.js` documentation generated?

**Other Research**

In case people suggest alternatives, I have already come across similarly attractive documentation solutions - ideally, i'd like to produce multi language documentation from source (javascript, python, css, mongodb):

http://daux.io

http://tripit.github.io/slate

https://readme.io

http://www.mkdocs.org

https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio

http://www.doctant.com

https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio

http://documentation.js.org

http://apidocjs.com

http://dokkerjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the library [comment.js](https://github.com/dciccale/comment.js) by the same author.